# Does Outlook trash folder disable links images from loading

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I received a spam E-mail saying my computer was under their control and as soon as I read the E-mail they would know and wanted me to pay som bitcoin or they would us my kontaktlist and humiliate me. 
I know this are just spam but my question is since this email was detected as junk by outlook I suppose the links in the E-mail never load any images. If they did the sender server would know I read it right!

I could not read anything on the junk folder so I ask here for advice.

Comment: No, trash is like any other regular folder - it will display HTML and load pictures.  Send the email to the Junk/Spam folder, then right-click on the Junk/Spam folder > Empty Folder. _(I'm assuming this is a question regarding Outlook, not the Outlook WebMail service [`outlook.com`].  If it's not, the steps for Outlook WebMail may be different, however it's recommended to never use WebMail sites and instead use desktop email clients which are vastly more effective at catching spam/malicious emails.)_

Comment: Actually it was the junk folder I'm in Sweden so junk folder is called trash, I update my Q

Comment: If that's the junk-mail folder, then yes... you'll immediately know if it is the junk-mail/spam folder if, when you view any email in it, the email is displayed in plain text with no HTML/rich text formatting

Comment: If you are using an Outlook desktop client, messages in Junk Emial folder will shown as plain text just like JW0914 said.